# Regex for nth line in a text file

Tags: regex, expression, powergrep

I've been trying to get this regex down and searched alot for answers
What I need is to get the nth (4th in this example) line from a text file
I got this down atm

```
^(?<=([^\n]*\n){3})[^\n]*\n
```

But it doesn't seem to work (something about needing fixed length patterns in lookbehind)
Is there any way to overcome that obstacle?

Can anyone provide a correction\different regex if needed for this problem?

Thanks

Edit:

I'm trying this regex in PowerGrep and it just doesn't work

P.S:
Is there a way of getting nth line in powergrep other than regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably need to use a capture buffer.
This regex uses MULTI_LINE mode.
Capture buffer 1 contains the 4th line

```
 #  (?:^[^\n]*\n){3}([^\n]*)

 (?: ^ [^\n]* \n ){3}
 ( [^\n]* )
```

Edit: here is the same thing without multi-line mode

```
 #  ^(?:[^\n]*\n){3}([^\n]*)

 ^ 
 (?: [^\n]* \n ){3}
 ( [^\n]* )
```

Comment: Thanks, the regex you gave works in theory but not in PowerGrep for some reason
I edited the question with the note about powergrep
thanks for the help anyhow

Comment: @user - I added a non multi-line equivalent, see if that works. I'd have to lookup PowerGrep to know why/if it doesn't work there.

Comment: I've tried that regex without multi line it doesn't work
it keeps returning the whole 4 lines as a result instead of only the 4th one

Comment: @user - Then it works! You just have to get capture buffer 1. You are getting capture buffer 0 (the whole match). Is it possible to get a capture buffer in PowerGrep?

Comment: What about Action Type: Collect Data, Collect `\1` ?

Comment: It shows the 4 lines in yellow and the 4th line right after it in green
I think that will do, but do you think there's a way to only leave the green part?
btw thanks for the help, I'm new to PowerGrep it never occured to me to search @ collect data :P

Comment: I looked at its screen shot. Yes, tell it to collect `\1`, capture group 1. That basically filters it. And the yellow is the whole match, green is capture group 1 (4th line).

Answer (score 0):

Much better just use Regex.Split

```
Regex.Split(text, "\n", RegexOptions.Multiline)(3)
```

That will give you the 4th line in a text string.