# KNIME regex expression to return 6th line

Tags: regex, knime

I have a column with string values present in several lines. I would like to only have the values in the 6th line, all the lines have varying lengths, but all the cells in the column have the information I need in the 6th line.

I am honestly absolutely new and have no background in Java nor KNIME - I have scoured this forum and other internet sources, and none seem to tackle what I need in KNIME specifically - I found something similar but it doesn't work in KNIME:

[Regex for nth line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008886/regex-for-nth-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Kindly, provide a sample input, the expected output, and include what you have tried so far in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will probably need to be broken into two parts

- How to do a regex search in KNIME
- How to do a regex search for the 6th line

I can help with the regex search, but I don't know KNIME

To start with, you want to know how to search for a single line which is

```
([^\n]*\n)
```

This looks for

- `*: 0 or more` of

  - `[^\n]: anything that isn't a new line`
- followed by `\n: a new line`
- and `(): groups them together into a single match`

We can then expand this into: `([^\n]*\n){5}([^\n]*\n){1}` Which creates 2 capture groups, one with the first 5 lines, the second with the 6th line.

If KNIME supports Non-Capturing groups you can then expand that into the following so that you only have one matching capture group.  You can decide for yourself which you like best.

```
(?:[^\n]*\n){5}([^\n]*\n){1}
```

I've created an [example](http://regexr.com/4i046) you can test on RegExr

Regardless of which way you go, make sure to document the regex with comments or stick it into a variable with a very clear name since they aren't particularly human readable